# Nest can't resolve dependencies without explicit type key in @Inject(...)

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs

I'm trying to solve another "Nest can't resolve dependencies" error, which you can find many examples of. I eventually added a `@Inject(Type)` decorator to the constructor parameter, which solved the issue. Nothing else changed. I would still like to understand why this worked/was necessary.

My first approach followed the examples very closely:

```
@Controller('consumer')
export class ConsumerController {
    constructor(private service: ConsumerService) {}
}
```

The result was that the application started successfully, but I could see the dependency wasn't satisfied because I could tell from runtime errors that the property was `undefined`.

Next, I added an explicit `@Inject()` like:

```
@Controller('consumer')
export class ConsumerController {
    constructor(@Inject() private service: ConsumerService) {}
}
```

This resulted in errors like `Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the ConsumerController (?). Please make sure that the argument dependency at index [0] is available in the ConsumerModule context.`

There are many example of people asking similar questions  and I went through them exhaustively. None of the root causes were applicable in my case.

I thought of trying a custom provider just to help debug the issue, which is when I realized that it's possible to pass the Class of the dependency as an argument to `@Inject()`. This led to the working version:

```
@Controller('consumer')
export class ConsumerController {
    constructor(@Inject(ConsumerService) private service: ConsumerService) {
    }
}
```

Note that *nothing about the module or provider changed* between these attempts. I thought that maybe there was a build artifact confusing things so I tried `rm -rf lib tsconfig.tsbuildinfo` and the behavior was the same.

I would really like to understand why Nest can't satisfy the dependency without the explicit type-key (maybe some tsconfig.json setting)?

*Edit*: Including module for reference:

```
@Module({
    controllers: [ConsumerController],
    providers: [ConsumerService],
})
export class ConsumerModule {}
```

Comment: You should not need `@Inject()` here. What does the module that contains this service look like?

Comment: looks like you got a circular dependency. See: https://docs.nestjs.com/faq/common-errors#cannot-resolve-dependency-error

Comment: @AlexWayne Updated question to include module.

Comment: @MicaelLevi There's no circular dependency, but if there were, the working copy would have it as well.

Comment: how did you import the file that has `ConsumerService`? Also, did your read the link I've shared?

Comment: my bet is that you got a circular file import, this is why the explicit version (via `@Inject()`) will work.

Comment: have you annotated the service with @Injectable() ?

Comment: @CruelEngine Yes, the service has @Injectable()